# Anomalous constrained scipy.optimize.minimze behavior based on initial conditions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm testing out `scipy.optimize` for another project and found some anomalous behavior when setting the initial conditions for minimizing using the SLSQP method. I assume this is because the sequential least squares algorithm, when initialized at a critical point (`start_pos1`) immediately returns without checking the second derivative conditions. I looked through the docs and didn't see anything, though--can anyone tell what's going on?

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np


def simplex(x):
    return 1 - sum(x)

def sphere_min(x):
    return sum(x[i]**2 for i in range(len(x)))**.5

def sphere_max(x):
    return -sphere_min(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dimensions = 3
    start_pos1 = np.ones(dimensions) * 1.0/dimensions
    start_pos2 = [2*float(i+1)/(dimensions*(dimensions+1)) for i in range(dimensions)]
    raw_start_pos = np.random.uniform(0, 1, dimensions)
    start_pos3 = raw_start_pos/raw_start_pos.sum()

    bnds = tuple((0, 1) for i in range(dimensions))
    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': simplex})

    for start_pos in (start_pos1, start_pos2, start_pos3):
        print 'Start Position: {}'.format(start_pos)
        res = optimize.minimize(sphere_min, start_pos, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
        print 'Min: x = {}, value = {}'.format(res.x, res.fun)
        res = optimize.minimize(sphere_max, start_pos, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
        print 'Max: x = {}, value = {}'.format(res.x, -res.fun)
        print '\n==============\n'
```